# How to mark the current select option to be selected

Tags: php

I have a select list on my view. After click on one of the options，the controller will refresh the page based on the selected option. However, the problem is after refreshing the page, the selected option isn't marked as selected. Also I want to sent the default `ALL` option to the controller when load the page, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is the View:

```
 <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php echo base_url("account/myaccount_ticketmanagement"); ?>"> 
 <select name="change_event" onchange="this.form.submit()" type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-top:-3px; width:60%; float: right; background-color: #414042; border:none; box-shadow: none; color: white;">
 <option value="ALL" selected="selected">ALL</option>
 <?php
       foreach ($e_names as $e_name){
       echo '<option value="'.$e_name[0]['e_name'].'">'.$e_name[0['e_name'].'</option>';     
                                        }
 ?>
 </select>
 </form>
```

This is the code in the controller:

```
 $current_E = $this->input->post('change_event');
 if(isset($current_E)&&!empty($current_E)){
   $data['record'] = $this->db->select('ticket_id, Qty, fullname,purchase_time, ticket_type, ticket_price, delivery')
                    ->where('user_id',$user_id)->get('Guest', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

 }
 else{
   if($current_E == 'ALL'){
     $data['record'] = $this->db->select('ticket_id, Qty, fullname, purchase_time, ticket_type, ticket_price, delivery')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get('Guest', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

   }
   else{
     $id = $this->db->select('event_id')->where('e_name',$current_E)->get('events')->result_array();
     $data['record'] = $this->db->select('ticket_id, Qty, fullname,purchase_time, ticket_type, ticket_price, delivery')->where('user_id',$user_id)->where('event_id',$id[0]['event_id'])->get('Guest', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
   }         
}
```

Comment: you need to use AJAX for this

Comment: also, it seems like you are making your database calls from the controller. This is wrong. Database queries should be done in your model.

Comment: @Thanks for the advice, this is just a testing version. Since I'm really struggling with the select list，I didn't have write a model for this. Is there any way else beside using AJAX? I barely know anything about AJAX.

Comment: well im assuming once your controller is completed then it refreshes the same page. If thats the case you can then return the chosen option and place it in your select dropdown as active if it `isset`. Think of it as setting a flag.

Comment: @CodeGodie That is exactly what happened. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the looks of the code, you are using the CodeIgniter framework.  If that's wrong, I'll delete this answer as it's going to be based heavily on that.

In the controller, you'll need to set a variable in $data for the `$current_E`.  Something like:

```
$data['current_E'] = $current_E;
```

In the view, to check this value against each option:

```
<?php
   foreach ($e_names as $e_name){
       echo '<option value="'.$e_name[0]['e_name'].'"';
       if ($e_name[0]['e_name'] == $current_E) {
           echo 'selected="selected"';
       }
       echo '>'.$e_name[0]['e_name'].'</option>';     
   }
 ?>
```

This will then cause the $selected_E value to add a selected to the required drop down option, and the last one of those in the select list will be the one the browser uses.

You could always add a check into the ALL option to see if $current_E is ALL before adding the selected attribute to that

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `$_POST`? Since your form as an POST `method` value, all your previous selection will be set in `$_POST`, so you could implement something like

```
echo '<option value="'.$e_name[0]['e_name'].'">'.$e_name[0['e_name'].(($_POST['change_event'])? "selected" : "" ) .'</option>';
```

to output your options, and

```
 <option value="ALL" <?= ((!$_POST['change_event'])? "selected" : "" )?> >ALL</option>
```

for your ALL option

P.S.: not tested, but should work.

Comment: I'm using codeigniter. That's why I'm not using PHP's POST method.